# What alternatives exist to using an object variant type with a duplicate field name across branches?

Tags: inheritance, nim-lang

Currently, creating an [object variant](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-object-variants) type like this:

```
type
  FooKind = enum a, b, c
  Foo = object
    case kind: FooKind
    of a:
      bar, a: int
    of b:
      bar, b: int
    of c:
      c: int
```

results in an error:

> Error: attempt to redefine: 'bar'

because the different branches of the variant cannot share fields. There's an [open issue about that](https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/19) but since it's over 3 years old and still unresolved, I'm not holding my breath.

I see a few possible alternatives:

- Making the "shared" fields common to all variants, which would pollute some variants with unnecessary fields:

```
type
  FooKind = enum a, b, c
  Foo = object
    bar: int
    case kind: FooKind
    of a:
      a: int
    of b:
      b: int
    of c:
      c: int
```

- Using a static enum, which seems to necessitate [additional workarounds](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/3150):

```
type
  FooKind = enum a, b, c
  Foo[K: static[FooKind]] = object
    when K == a:
      bar, a: int
    elif K == b:
      bar, b: int
    elif K == c:
      c: int
```

- Using regular object inheritance:

```
type
  FooKind = enum a, b, c
  FooBase = object
    kind: FooKind
  FooA = object of FooBase
    bar, a: int
  FooB = object of FooBase
    bar, b: int
  FooC = object of FooBase
    c: int
```

What other alternatives are there to getting around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, another way of dealing with the problem is avoiding the redefinition through prefixing of the affected variables:

```
type
  FooKind = enum a, b, c
  Foo = object
    case kind: FooKind
    of a:
      aBar, a: int
    of b:
      bBar, b: int
    of c:
      c: int
```

While your example attempts to *reuse* the type of `bar`, you could as well have an integer `bar` in a branch of the variant and a float `bar` in another, also causing confusion for the reader of the code at the *callsite*. Maybe using the same name for everything might not be such a good idea after all.